# Want to show console output in my tkinter window continously, without text grid

Tags: python, tkinter

[I made a virtual assistant is python language[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ROuB.jpg) , and I want to show console outputs in my tinter windows. I try to do this many time but i am not able to do this.
I used python's tkinter funtion label but it did not giving me any kind of output on tkinter window, So please help me to get desirable output.][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ROuB.jpg)

```
from cProfile import label
import tkinter as tk
from telnetlib import SE
from tkinter import BOTTOM, LEFT, NW, RIGHT, SW, Button, Label, StringVar, Tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from email.mime import audio
from logging import exception
from unittest import result

import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os


def Voice_Assistant():
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
    def speak(audio):
        engine.say(audio)
        engine.runAndWait()
    def wishme():
        hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
        if hour>=0 and hour<12:
            speak("Good Morning sir")
        elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
            speak("Good Afternoon sir")
        else:
            speak("Good evening sir")

        speak("I am Zaara, Please tell me how may i help you")        
    def takeCommand():
        
        # It takes microphone input form the user and returns string output
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening....")
            l1=Label(window, text="Listening....").pack()
            r.pause_threshold = 0.5
            r.energy_threshold = 2000
            audio = r.listen(source)
            
        try:
            print("Recognizing...")
            r1=Label(window, text="Recognizing...", justify='left', background='light blue').grid(row=9, column=6)
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
            print(f"User said : {query}\n")
            r1=Label(window, text=f"User said : {query}\n", justify='left', background='light blue').grid(row=9, column=6)
            
       
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e)  
            print("Say it again please...")
            r2=Label(window, text="Say it again please...", justify='left', background='light blue').grid(row=9, column=6)
            return "None"
        return query
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        wishme()
        while True:
            query = takeCommand().lower() 

            # Logic for executing tasks based on query
            if 'wikipedia' in query:
                speak('searching wikipedia....')
                query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
                speak("According to wikipedia")
                print(results)
                speak(results)

            elif 'open youtube' in query:
                webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
                speak("ok! i'll open Youtube for you")

            elif 'open google' in query:
                webbrowser.open("google.com")
                speak("ok! i'll open google for you")

            elif 'stack overflow' in query:
                webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")
                speak("ok! i'll open stack overflow for you")

            elif 'play music' in query:
                music_dir = 'D:\\Downloads\\music01'
                songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
                # print(songs)
                os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[13]))
                speak("ok i'll play music for you")
                

            elif 'what is time now' in query:
                strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H: %M: %S")
                speak(f"sir, the time is {strTime}")

            elif 'open powerpoint' in query:
                codepath = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\PowerPoint 2016.lnk"
                os.startfile(codepath)
                speak("ok! i'll open power point for you")
                
            elif 'open chrome' in query:
                codepath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
                os.startfile(codepath)
                speak("ok! i'll open google chrome for you")

            elif 'quit' in query:
                speak("ok! i'll quit your program")
                exit()

            elif 'open my university website' in query:
                webbrowser.open("gbu.ac.in")
                speak("ok! i'll open your university website for you")
            
            elif 'open control panel' in query:
                codepath = "C:\\Users\\ik597\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\System Tools\\Control Panel.lnk"
                os.startfile(codepath)
                speak("ok! i'll open control panel for you")

            elif 'open ms word' in query:
                codepath = "C:\\Users\\ik597\\OneDrive\\Attachments\\Desktop\\Word 2016.lnk"
                os.startfile(codepath)
                speak("ok! i'll open microsoft word for you")

            elif 'open monkey type' in query:
                webbrowser.open("Monkeytype.com")
                speak("ok! i'll open monkeytype for you")  

            elif 'open passport india portal' in query:
                webbrowser.open("passportindia.org.in")
                speak("ok! i'll open passport india portal for you")

            # Talk to zara
            elif 'what is your name' in query:
                speak("My name is zaara")
            elif 'open This pc' in query:
                speak("I can't open")  
            elif 'how are you' in query:
                speak('I am fine, thanks. How about yourself') 
            elif 'can you be my friend' in query:
                speak('Of course, I am your VFF virtual friend forever')     





window =tk.Tk()
window_width=680
window_height=500
window.minsize(680,500)
window.maxsize(680,500)
screen_width=window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height=window.winfo_screenheight()
center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)
window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
window.configure(bg='light blue')

img = Image.open('voice1.png')
img1=Image.open('button.png')
window.iconbitmap("V logo.ico")
window.title("Zara- The Virtual Assistant")

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
button= Button(window, image=photo, borderwidth=0, cursor="hand2", background='light blue', command=Voice_Assistant)
button.place(x=315,y=300)

inputtxt = tk.Text(window,height = 2,width = 70)
inputtxt.place(x=25,y=450)

photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
button= Button(window, image=photo1, borderwidth=0, cursor="hand2", background='light blue')
button.place(x=602,y=443)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that strikes my eye is that you are using a "while True"-loop.
Your program will start the window and everything and after that go into the continuous "while True"-loop.
Because of that Tkinter will no longer be refreshed from that point on. This is the reason why Windows will tell you that the Window is not responding.
Because it is not refreshed, you can't dynamically change anything.
The only solution i know of, would be to use multithreading.
You basically need to put your Voice Assistant in a class and then use Python multithreading to let it run on another thread.
You should then be abled to just add a label to your Window containing the text you want to display.
For a tutorial on threading in python you can check out this site: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: @RajkumarVerma No Problem, would be great if you could mark my response as the solution so the question is marked as solved.